# Access SQL Express database from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sql-server-express

I'm trying to access an SQL Express database from an iPhone/iPad app. I would like to login, see what's in there and make some changes.

Is this safe? Is it even possible?

Anyone has any idea? I'm not looking for a complete source code, just something to start with.

I couldn't find anything on Apple Docs so I'm a little septic about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means the SQLExpress is on another machine/server.  the best practice would be to expose your data as a web service (REST or SOAP).  There's plenty of iPhone APIs to consume REST http services.

That's kind of the point of web services - to make cross platform interop between machines and decoupled services possible.

I did a write up on accessing a C# service via iPhone here:

[Developing a client-server iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616400/developing-a-client-server-iphone-app/7620609#7620609)